# Select2 remote data: select value Null

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I render my dropdownlist in mvc razor like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedContact, new SelectList(Model.ContactList, "ContactId", "Name", Model.SelectedContact), "(Geen)", new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @data_search = "false", @id = "DASearchContactId" })
```

SelectedContact property is a nullable int.

With javascript I create the select2 with remote data:

```
    $("#DASearchContactId").select2({
        dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop",
        ajax: {
            url: '@Url.Action(MVC.DigitaalArchief.GetContactList4Paging())',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 500,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    searchText: params.term, // search term
                    page: params.page,
                    pageLimit: 20
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                params.page = params.page || 1;

                return {
                    results: data.items,
                    pagination: {
                        more: (params.page * 20) < data.total_count
                    }
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
```

After the page is rendered, the default value for Null is showed: [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vAyc.jpg)

If you click on the dropdown, the following is showed: [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiCf1.jpg)

After I have selected an option, I can't select the value Null anymore by the User Interface.

**Question:**
How can I accomplish to select the value Null with the User Interface with remote data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear selected value using:

```
  $("#DASearchContactId").select2({ allowClear: true,placeholder: "Select a value"  });
```

property.

Comment: This doesn't work. I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: I made some mistake you also need to add placeholder  like :   
    placeholder: "Select a value"